# 1 ViewController and 2 modalViews Delegation

Tags: iphone, delegates, uibutton, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

Is it possible for 1 ViewController to be the delegate for 2 ModalViews? I have this FlipsideViewController and I want it to have 2 different UIButtons. Each button will present a different view modally.

I made everything but wondering about the following syntax of delegation. FlipsideViewController should be the delegate for CustomImagePicker and also the delegate for the AboutViewController

```
@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController <CustomImagePickerDelegate> <AboutViewControllerDelegate>
```

Needless to say the complier isn't happy about the above code line.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. For example, in code:

```
@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController <CustomImagePickerDelegate, AboutViewControllerDelegate>
```